# How to add custom input field on product page in 1.9.2?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

i am making a garments/dresses webstore and i need to have fields, on product page, like a user can enter certain number or name to print on a shirt or select something similar from a dropdown list. How can i achieve this??
For selecting sizes i have created an attribute but for above i am unable to do it by creating attribute.

Comment: Try with custom option

Comment: @Kothari could you please explain a little more?

Comment: You want a dropdown if user select size that time amount also increase and some text boxes for user entering right

Comment: Yes i have done the sizes input NOW  i need an input field where customer can enter a value he/she needs to print on a T-shirt.

Comment: then add a custom input field under custom option

Comment: you want like http://www.picksilk.com/blouses/zardosi-work-designer-blouse.html this right

Comment: @Kothari yes exactly this is what i want but it should not be necessary to fill like it should be optional.

Comment: Ok go to any product go to last tab custom option and then add

Comment: set is required no

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

Login Your Back end go to `catalog-> Manage Product-> Open any product -> left side select last option Custom Option`

There you have to select Input field and what ever you want and then set is required for mandatroy if you want to set yes other wise set no

Answer (score 2):

On magento 2.1 it is in `Products -> Catalog -> edit -> Customizable Options -> Add Option`

Answer (score 0):

I have done in magento-version 2.2.4 .In your  Back end go to catalog-> Product-> Open any product -> Customizable Option.[image]Please find the attached screenshot.

My final product page view look like below attached image.[image]